# New terminal working directory

Tags: ssh, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

When I login (using `ssh`) to other host and open a new tab (pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>). It sets current working directory to a particular directory in my home independent from current working directory on remote host.

- So what can be the reason for this behavior?
- And how can I change it?

I am using RedHat.

Comment: You're creating local tabs, on the local terminal, which is totally separate from the remote session you have running within one of those tabs?  Or do I misunderstand?  The Ctrl-Shift-T is being intercepted by the terminal application and not passed through `ssh`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is strange to me too. When I press the same combination of keys from a tab that is not ssh connected to the remote host it works fine.

Comment: Nope, I still don't understand.  Can you describe step by step what is happening, with examples.

Comment: use `screen` or `tmux` if you want to open new tabs in the remote sessions. Or use `X11` forwarding and open new `xterm` from the existing shell.

Comment: I open a terminal and press CTRL + SHIFT + T and it opens a new tab and the current working directory in the new tab is the same as in original tab. Now I open a terminal and ssh to other host and press  CTRL + SHIFT + T, but now it opens a new terminal having current working directory set to some particular directory which is in my home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, Gnome-terminal looks at the current directory of the process that's running in this tab, and switches to that directory to run the process in the new tab.

Observe that if you type `bash` in a Gnome-terminal tab that's already running a shell and is in `/directory1`, and you run `cd /directory2` in that instance of bash, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> launches a new tab with a shell in `/directory1`. Gnome-terminal only looks at its child process's current directory, not at its descendants. (That's the only reasonable way, really: how would it decide which descendant to pick?)

When you run `ssh` to open a shell on another machine, Gnome-terminal does what it always do: when you open a new tab, that tab starts in the directory of the shell from which you ran the `ssh` command.

Gnome-terminal has no way to know about the current directory on another machine. To do that, it would need some very tight integration with SSH and with the remote shell. I'm not saying it's impossible — Emacs's [Tramp](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) parses the prompt from the remote shell to figure out the remote directory — but it has a cost in complexity, reliability and flexibility. Gnome-terminal gives you a terminal and lets you do what you want in it; Tramp takes control of the SSH connection and doesn't cope with arbitrary behavior of the remote shell.

You cannot change this without doing some nontrivial development work. You could use Emacs as your terminal emulator (but of course Emacs is far from being a drop-in replacement for Gnome-terminal, you'd need to pick up different habits). If all you need to do on the remote machine is manipulate files and not run programs, you can mount the files over [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS), and then you'd only be running a local shell so you'd get the current directory tracking that you want. But by far the simplest way to create a new tab in the same remote directory is to create a new tab, run the same `ssh` command, and copy-paste the remote path.