# How to retrieve the current working directory inside an ssh client process from outside the process?

Tags: ssh, directory

I am trying to find which directory an `ssh` client process is inside of on the remote host.

This information is generally displayed in the top of a `gnome-terminal` during an `ssh` connection.

**EDIT1:** I need to get this information outside of the `ssh` process.

Comment: What are you doing at the time? Are you at a shell or running a single command or..?

Comment: @Guy I am creating the ssh process with `ssh user@host` in a bash shell.

Comment: Just pwd then? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Guy I need to get this information outside of the ssh process.

Comment: An answer to a slightly different question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267229 may be of interest though. Maybe someone will have a better idea in a bit.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve this info from the client or server SSH process?

Comment: From the client computer. @multithr3at3d

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please be as specific as possible the next time you ask question here. We don't like unclear questions. Being new here, you should read: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: IMHO impossible, since `ssh` protocol is self-encrypted. But in Linux world anything's possible, let's wait.

Comment: Would examining `/proc/<PID>/cwd` on the remote host cover this ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do this I've read on superuser ([Get remote working directory of existing SSH session](https://superuser.com/questions/1203273/get-remote-working-directory-of-existing-ssh-session)) is to ssh onto the remote host again, find the cwd from there, and then bring that info back to the client for further use.

I'm not fond of this approach because of how many steps are involved, but it may work in a pinch.